# Suppress Xcode warning? 'weak_import' attribute ignored

Tags: xcode, gcc

I've got quite a large Xcode project that since an Xcode upgrade is giving me loads of

"'weak_import' attribute ignored"

warnings, they are coming from WebKit, and a bit of research suggests it's a compiler bug.

Is there anyway to suppress them, I'm getting thousands, making the 'real' warnings impossible to find.

Cheers

MT

Answer (score -2):

Try adding '-Wno-attributes' to the Other Warning Flags in the Xcode project's build settings.

Comment: cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-attribute"

Maybe I need to specify it somewhere else...

Comment: Sorry, that's "-Wno-attributes".

Comment: Same problem, I think I need a later version of Xcode+GCC,  which I can't as I'm running on Leopard.